# Pager should start from last page instead of first one

Tags: views, paging

I have a block view including pager and shown on front page. when I go to front page I see the pager under block shown in normal way(ie start from first page). But I want that pager start from last page instead of first one.

**Result of My View:**

[image]

**Result that I want:**

I want that when I visit my view, it's pager should look like this
[image]

Comment: @kiamlaluno & Krishna Mohan I have updated my question for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

At the view, you can use SORT CRITERIA. It can help you arrange in post date, title page or even content field.[image]

Comment: But @peifa i dont want to change the sorting order of posts, i just want to get a focus on "LAST" page while displaying view at first time.

Comment: Still have to use SORT CRITERIA, but maybe different setting. Example: At content type create a field call "Pages". Fill them by just key in the number such as 1,2,3,4,5,6,7. At  SORT CRITERIA, filter choose content and search pages. Pages will sort according base you Pages. There is my long way method. You can find a better solution, but need to set sort criteria.

Comment: That's for the comments. Did you find a similar solution for views ?